# Add changed row number to mail body

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm running Outlook in background. Using Excel 2010.

I want to do following:

- send an automatic mail to defined persons
- the body of the mail should contain the row and column number where the change happened
- it should only work for cells in one specified column

I have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim APP_OUTLOOK As Object
Dim MESSAGE As Object

Set APP_OUTLOOK = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MESSAGE = APP_OUTLOOK.CreateItem(0)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1048576")) Is Nothing Then
    With MESSAGE
        .To = "name.name@name.com"
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = "hey buddy, something has changed please have a look at cell: "
'the text should show: "hey buddy, something has changed please have a look at cell: A25000."
        .Display
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

- It should only send the mail if the value in the cell is changed from "" to something or changed from a value to another value
- It has to be dynamic because I can't specify an exact cell
- The cell contains a date in the format "dd.mm.yy"

---

With the help of Zac I was able to solve my problem.

Here is the working code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim APP_OUTLOOK As Object
Dim MESSAGE As Object

Set APP_OUTLOOK = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MESSAGE = APP_OUTLOOK.CreateItem(0)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1048576")) Is Nothing Then
        With MESSAGE
            .To = "name.name@name.com"
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = "hey buddy," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "the file has been modified" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "following cell has a new entry: " & Target.Address & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "the new entry has the value " & Target.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "please check the excel file" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "best wishes," & vbNewLine & "me"
            .Display
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

- I have added Target.Text to display the value and Target.Address is to display the cell row and column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but it looks like it should work. To get the address of the cell changed, add `Target.Address` at the end of your `.Body` statement